# Can't install/update/remove apps "trying to overwrite... which is also in..."

Tags: apt, dpkg

While installing updating or removing any app, I get this error:

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
winetricks : Depends: cabextract
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

And when I run `sudo apt -f install`, I get this error:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  cabextract
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cabextract
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/21.4 kB of archives.
After this operation, 112 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 282096 files and directories currently 
installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../cabextract_1.6-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cabextract (1.6-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/cabextract_1.6-
1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/icons/cab_extract.png', which is also 
in package zorinos-icons 10.0~xenial~NoobsLab.com
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/cabextract_1.6-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: ZorinOS is offtopix here. If you are really using Ubuntu, please specify its version and show us the output of `apt-cache policy zorinos-icons`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since apt was not working, I could not execute
    sudo apt purge zorinos-icons
So i had to manually remove those contents by searching via file manager in root mode. Now it is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the package `zorinos-icons`. It is not official and prevents `cabextract` from installing by providing the same file.